# Using Integrated Windows Authentication in a Perl Dancer App

Tags: perl, active-directory, windows-authentication, dancer, strawberry-perl

I am currently building a web app with Perl Dancer.  This app requires users to authenticate using my company's Active Directory.  To avoid prompting users for their usernames and passwords, I would like to use Integrated Windows Authentication.  However, I am having a hard time locating any documentation that explains how to use this type of authentication with Perl--let alone with the Dancer framework.  At this point, I am not sure if I'll be deploying this app on Apache or IIS, so something that can work with both would be preferable.  Does anyone have any suggestions to help me get started?

Comment: Try googling around mod_perl and ntlm as a start. I'm not sure how this works if it's bypassing the webserver though.

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  There are a few things specific to Apache/mod_perl, but since I'm unsure how this app will get deployed, I was hoping to find something more generic.

Comment: After some additional searching, I thought of a question--could Plack/PSGI handle this for me?  There are some Plack authentication modules available, but I'm not sure about Integrated Windows Authentication.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What about Authen::NTLM?  Does anyone have experience using that module?

Answer (score 3):

Checked around and found someone else had had this very question on PerlMonks and it appears to have worked for them. I'm in the process of testing it out right now.

Question on PerlMonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=821419

The original poster stated that they used the following guide:
http://sivel.net/2007/05/sso-apache-ad-1

All reference using perl module:
[https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2::AuthenNTLM](https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2%3a%3aAuthenNTLM)

Edit: It works!

1. Make sure your apache config loads the ntlm.conf file
2. Do not use the entire fqdn for your PDC; just the hostname.
3. 'PerlSetVar ntlmdebug 1' is helpful. Just remember to turn it off afterwards.